# Issue in clicking icons in Recycler view in android 12

Tags: android, android-12

I have coded an app using the recycler view to give user options to click icons and followed by do the tasks. These options are dynamically fetch from an API. The concern is This app is working fine in some devices and not working in other devices. These Icons are clikable and app is working normally in all the android 11 devices, as well as it is working fine in oneplus android 12 device, whereas in realme, vivo and samsung devices having android 12 os icons are not clickable. I don't know what is going wrong with these devices.

I have tried to upgrade all the dependancies, and almost search for the same on all the platform still not able to solve the same.

I thought the error was due to the flavored UI given by these perticular brands, but don't know what is going wrong in this.

If anyone have faced the same issue please share what needed to be done to get this resolve.

PS: I probably can't share the code. I can create a sample app for the perticular issue and will share once it is ready.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted, as some code was blocking the UI thread, which ultimately caused the issue.

Comment: Don't make comment to an answer. if something has solve your problem and you are not able to make comment on it then just leave the question for best answer.